# How to test builds on 'test' nodes without changing jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

We have builds that run off jenkinsfiles using the GitHub Branch Source plugin. They look something like this

```
try {
    node("SomeSetOfNodes") {
      stage('Build'){
         //do something
      }
}
```

Now let's assume i want to make some changes to a node that's in SomeSetOfNodes and then test builds on it to make sure i didn't break anything. I can take the label off that node which will prevent that node being used in production while i'm testing. But how do I get test builds to run on it? The only way i know how is to modify the "SomeSetOfNodes" in every single jenkinsfile that i want to test, which if you have 1 or 2 might be ok, but if you have 30 is a problem. For each one i have to create a branch, change the label commit and push and then build. It doesn't make sense that i would need to change code to do that. There has to be a better way.

What I expect is some way to override the label when I click on the build button. Something like a build with ovverides where I can redirect SomeSetOfNodes for this run of the build. I'm sure this is a common use case.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

One way to make this work would be to have a parameter `build_node` that defaults to `SomeSetOfNodes` but can be set to `YourTestNode`.

Not nice but should work.

Comment: Where would i set it to "YourTestNode"? I would have to do it in the jenkinsfile, which comes back to the same problem of having to change many jenkinsfiles to point to it

Comment: In the parameter field when starting the job

Comment: I don't have a parameter field when starting the job. With the GitHub Branch Source it reads the content of git and creates the jobs without exposing any parameters. How can I create such an optional parameter with a default set up? That would be awesome.

Comment: Don't know that plugin. But there should be a checkbox in the config "this job is parameterzed"